# Flutter (iOS/Android): Keep WebSocket Connection Alive in Background

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, websocket

I have a Flutter application in which it connects to the server using **socket_io_client**. The purpose of this connection is to listen to server messages about order requests which the clients place through a separate app. Here is a small demo:

**Client places order** --*websocket*--> **Server finds available fulfiller** --*websocket*--> **Fulfiller receives request.**

The problem is that when I lock the phone's screen (testing on physical iOS device), the WebSocket connection disconnects. How can I keep this alive?

Here is my WebSocket code in Flutter:

```
Future<void> _connectViaSocket() async {
  socket ??= IO.io(
    'http://localhost:3000/orders/fulfiller',
    IO.OptionBuilder()
      .setTransports(['websocket'])
      .disableAutoConnect()
      .build(),
  );
  if (socket!.disconnected) {
    socket!.connect();
  }
  socket!.on('order-request', (data) {
    print("Order request.");
  });
}
```

Comment: When you lock your phone, or the app enter background state, it will terminated your socket anyway. For this scenario, please consider using ``background mode`` or ``notification`` check apple document about ``background mode``